# Understanding the distribution of data?

Tags: r, distributions, dataset

Please help me to understand the type of the distribution of my data (width values shown below). I am providing three graphs: 1) scatter plot; 2) histogram; and 3) qqplot (variable width).  Interval_number is just a serial number. Width is nothing but the time in seconds for arriving a set of 100 things.

My data:

```
interval_number  width
1                   34 
2                  234 
3                  124
....                ..
```

[image: plot]

[image: histogram]

[image: qqnorm]

Comment: which variable is the QQ plot showing?

Comment: Just updated. Its width.

Comment: I think we will need more information to be helfpul.  For example, what sort of variable is "interval number"?  Is there only one observation for each interval number?  What is width?  What other variables might be relevant?  What if anything would we expect theoretically or from other grounds the relationship of the two to be?

Comment: Please see the update.

Comment: This histogram suggests that you look for 4 or so subpopulations, each with their own distribution.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this looks like there is a mixture of three different behaviours, so
the overall marginal behaviour is

```
p(W) = p(W | m_0)p(m_0) + p(W | m_1 )p(m_1)+p(W|m_2) p(m_2)
```

My interpretation is that each of your width measurements is that it is the rtime required to get 100 events.  In this case,  I'd first try using a [Gamma Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) for each of the `p(W | m_i)`; this corresponds to an assumption of independent, exponentially distributed, waiting times between events.

The usual way to go about fitting a mixture model to data is to use the [Expectation-Maximization algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm).

Comment: Two thoughts:
1) Have you tried a plot of log(width)? 
2) If width is time to collect 100 things, then it could be influenced a lot by arrival of 1 thing, couldn't it?

Comment: Thank you. But, I didn't see any significant difference with log(width) in the above plots.